# How to forbid adding smaller number that already exist in mongodb with same objectId?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

If I have VoterTurnout collection like this:

```
_id: ObjectId("5ae4e704b7bccf133c24f0b8")
electoralUnit:ObjectId("5ab906612f30fe23dc592591")
turnoutByHour:"08:00"
voterTurnout:11
safeVoter:1
date:2018-04-28T21:26:28.678Z
__v:0
```

how to forbid that next input, that would be in 09::00 in field turnoutByHour, can't be voterTurnout field smaller number than 11 but only when electoranUnit is the same id?

I imaged something with if statement like:

```
if (req.body.voterTurnout < VoterTurnouts.findOne({voterTurnout : req.params.voterTurnout }))
```

**but can't figure out how to add and turnoutByHour and electoranUnit in that logic...?**

I already have a lot if statement with errors messages in route:

```
router.post('/', (req, res)=>{
    let errors = [];

    if (!req.body.electoralUnit) {
      errors.push({message: 'Must chooose Electoral Unit!'});
    }
    if (!req.body.voterTurnout) {
      errors.push({message: 'Must add Voter Turnout!'});
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      res.render('home/voterTurnouts/index', {
        errors: errors,
        electoralUnit: req.body.electoralUnit,
        voterTurnout: req.body.voterTurnout
      });
    } else {
      VoterTurnout.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(voterTurnout=>{
          const newVoterTurnout = VoterTurnout({
            electoralUnit: req.body.electoralUnit,
            turnoutByHour: req.body.turnoutByHour,
            voterTurnout: req.body.voterTurnout,
            safeVoter: req.body.safeVoter
          });
          newVoterTurnout.save().then(savedVoterTurnout=>{
            ElectoralUnit.find({}).then(electoralUnits=>{
              res.redirect('/voterTurnouts');
            });
          }).catch(errors=>{
            req.flash('error_message', 'Hours are already added with that Electoral Unit!');
            res.redirect('/voterTurnouts');
          });
      });
    }
});
```

so I just need to add this one...

Comment: This is very easy?Use if statemant after xxx.findOne?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean and how is suppose to look?

Comment: Oke xxx.findone({....}).exec(function(err,result){if(req.body.voter..<result.voter...){....} ; })

Comment: But, how to include turnoutByHour and electoranUnit into if statement? I add route you to see that I have a lot of if statements with errors messages but I don't know how to add this one.